# Converting all <NA> into nan in pandas dataframe - python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan, na

I have a pandas dataframe with floats and strings and few `<NA>` and `nan`. I am trying to locate all the `<NA>` and convert them into `nan` using the following function `pd.to_numeric(....., errors='coerce')`. Also making sure that floats and strings remain untouched. Could you please help me with it?
Also when I `df.to_dict('list')` I get few `''` and `<NA>`.
Thank you.

Comment: What exactly are your `<NA>`? strings? `pd.NA`? and why do you need `float('nan')`? Please provide a reproducible object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether you have string `<NA>` or pandas NA (`pd.NA`), both should be converted to `nan` using [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [1, '1', 'a', float('nan'), pd.NA, '<NA>']})

pd.to_numeric(df['col'], errors='coerce')
```

Output:

```
0    1.0
1    1.0
2    NaN
3    NaN
4    NaN
5    NaN
Name: col, dtype: float64
```

If you want to replace specific items, keeping the strings, rather use:

```
df['col'].replace({'<NA>': float('nan'), pd.NA: float('nan')})
```

Output:

```
0      1
1      1
2      a
3    NaN
4    NaN
5    NaN
Name: col, dtype: object
```

If you need string representations of number as numbers, and other strings intact while removing `<NA>`/`pd.NA`:

```
out = (pd.to_numeric(df['col'], errors='coerce')
         .fillna(df['col'].replace({'<NA>': float('nan'), pd.NA: float('nan')}))
       )
```

Output:

```
0    1.0
1    1.0
2      a
3    NaN
4    NaN
5    NaN
Name: col, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @mozway
When I try `df.iloc[1, 6].replace({'<NA>': float('nan'), pd.NA: float('nan')})` I get: `AttributeError: 'NAType' object has no attribute 'replace'`. My `df` is a pandas dataframe and `type(df.iloc[1, 6])` is `pandas._libs.missing.NAType`. Any idea what happens here?

Comment: Can you provide the output of `df.to_dict('list')` as edit to your question?

Comment: I get few `''` and `<NA>`.

Comment: Can you please be explicit and provide the exact output? Your description is not enough for [reproducibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).